# Azure Devops server cascade field in work-items

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

We couldn't find any option in Azure Devops server to have workitems with cascaded fields option, so that we can have a picklist of items based on the root field.

It seems the cascade plugin/extension available only for Azure Devops service and is there any way to achieve this feature in Azure Devops server Dev18.M170.8 ?

Comment: This one may work for you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SCB-Brahma.SCB-Picker-Fields-Control

Comment: I suspect the Microsoft extension may work on Azure DevOps Server, but the team maintaining these tasks no longer tests them on Azure DevOps Server. If you query the rest API you can download the vsix, extract it to change the supported targets and then upload them to the server's local marketplace.

Comment: Looking for Microsoft approved extension as we are in our Prod ADO server

Comment: There is no such thing as a Microsoft approved extension. There are extensions published under the Microsoft Publisher, these are built by Microsoft and supported by Microsoft. The Microsoft DevLabs is a collection of extensions maintained by 'trusted' community members, but no additional quality control or approval is done to them beyond that. Your organisation is responsible to do its own security validation of all extensions. Microsoft doesn't do anything more than a virus scan when a new version is published.

Comment: I maintain a few myself, including a few under the DevLabs publisher.

Comment: This pretty much still applies: https://jessehouwing.net/security-state-of-the-azure-devops-marketplace/

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.cascading-picklists-extension . I could find this extension but not sure, this will support in azuredevops server.

Comment: Technically no, I haven't tried what happens if you patch the manifest, in theory it's just fine, but the team behind it isn't guaranteeing it to work.